# Get data in a Many-to-many relashionship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have three Entities:

```
public class KeywordSearch
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
}

public class Keyword
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PTCouncil PTCouncil { get; set; }                 <---------- EDIT

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
}

public class PTCouncil                                       <---------- EDIT
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Based on a set of words, I need to extract all the Distinct Address Id's.

The words are searched in the KeywordSearch table, that match a Keyword, related to an address.

So far, with the help of William, I have this, but get keywords that match all and some of the words to search, and I need to get them all:

EDIT:

```
var addressIds = (
              from ks in keywordSearchQuery
              where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
              select ks.Keyword.Addresses.Select(k => k.Id)
             )
             .ToList()
             .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b));
```

Example:

```
KeywordSearch = {1,"RENAULT",1},{2,"MORAIS",2},{3,"SOARES",3},{4,"CENTRO",4}
Keyword       = {1,"Renault",{1,2}},{2,"Morais",{1}},{3,"Soares",{1}},{4,"Centro",{2}}
Address       = {1,"Renault Morais Soares",{1,2,3}},{2,"Renault Centro",{1,2}}

If I search "RENAULT MORAIS SOARES", I should get AddressId = 1
If I search "RENAULT CENTRO", I should get AddressId = 2
If I search "RENAULT", I should get AddressId = 1,2

Actual Search Problem: If I search "RENAULT XXXX", I get 1,2 and I should get nothing.
```

I also need to filter by location, I have tried this but I get an error "The specified type member 'PTCouncil' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

```
keywordsAddressIds = from ks in keywordSearchQuery
                     where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
                     select ks.Keyword.Addresses.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(centerPoint) < radius * 1000).Select(a => a.Id);
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this in two operations I think.

First get all keywords addresses:

```
var result = from ks in keywordSearchQuery
           where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
           select ks).ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b));
```

then see if all keywords have a result, if not, don't return anything

```
if (splitKeywords.Any(s => !result.Any(t => t.Name.Contains(s))))
            {
                return null;
            }
```

This is pseudo code, but I think you should be able to figure it out from here.

---

--EDIT--
Just out of curiosity, aren't you already using more than one operation? Is it to prevent DB call unless all criteria is fullfilled?
But when you do a .ToList() you populate the list with data from DB (operation 1) and then to an Aggregate + Intersect (operation 2?). I assume you could add the second operation in the same way (code not tested) ->

```
var result = from ks in keywordSearchQuery
               where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
               select ks).ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b)).Any(s => !result.Any(t => t.Name.Contains(s)));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I also think that this is one way, but I was trying to reach using only one operation...

Comment: Hi, in the code "Any(s => !result.Any(t => t.Name.Contains(s)));" where comes from the "result" value?

Comment: sorry I was too quick to post the code. I can't really see how (or why) to do this in one operation. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are a few questions now going on here, I'll focus on the keyword portion of the question:

#### If the splitKeywords just needs to INTERSECT with an address' keywords (original answer)

```
var addressIds = (
                  from ks in keywordSearchQuery
                  where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
                  select ks.Keyword.Addresses.Select(k => k.Id)
                 )
                 .ToList()
                 .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b));
```

#### If the splitKeywords must be a SUBSET of an address' keywords

Notice how I'm referencing your context's `addresses` directly and not going through your `keywordSearchQuery` anymore. It's simpler this way.

```
var addressIds = (
                  from a in addresses
                  where !splitKeywords.Except(a.Keywords.Select(kw => kw.Name)).Any()
                  select a.Id
                 )
                 .ToList();
```

I tested both of these on my end by linking to hard coded objects. The new ***subset*** query might not work in LINQ to Entities. Let me know!

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm getting the error:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] Aggregate[IEnumerable`1](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ah! LINQ to Entities can't convert the .Aggregate() call into SQL. I edited my answer to fix this. Note the '.ToList()' I added to the query just before the .Aggregate() call. This will ensure the data is loaded from the database before attempting to intersect the collections. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi William, I found an issue in the code, if I search a sentence like "RENAULT MORAIS SORA" where "SORA" that don't belong in any KeywordSearch record, the query returns anyway the other keywords, and it can't, because I only want Keywords that match all KeywordSearch. Any idea how can we change it to solve this issue?

Comment: BTW William, I also need to apply a filter to the Addresses of the Keyword, "Addresses.Where(p => p.PTCouncil.NameStandard == locationStandard)", but I get the error "The specified type member 'PTCouncil' is not supported in LINQ to Entities", any idea? I have edit the question with this entity. Thanks

Comment: @Patrick, it wasn't clear in your original question that matching addresses must have the queried keywords as a ***subset*** of the address' keywords. I updated my answer with a query that uses subsets rather than intersections.

Comment: Hi William, I think you did not understand the problem. The search have to remain in the KeyworSearch because it's where the splited words have to be searched (Keyword entity is the "father" of all KeywordSearch). The issue here is that "splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)" expression only returns Keywords that match at least one KeywordSearch, and I need to get all of them, or else if I try RENAULT XXXXX it will return 1,2,3 and it can't return anything because we don't have the KeywordSearch XXXXX. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to use Aggregate and Intersect:

```
 var result = (from ks in keywordSearchQuery
               where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
               select ks.Keyword.Addresses.Select(a => a.Id))
              .Aggregate((l1, l2) => l1.Intersect(l2))
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm getting the error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] Aggregate[IEnumerable`1](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Patrick that is because Entity Framework does not know how to translate the Aggregate function into SQL. keywordSearchQuery is probably an IQueryable but should be an IEnumerable.

Comment: Hi, ok thanks. But it'e returning Any keywords, and I need to garanty all keywords to be found, any ideia?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use inner join that is also used to get data from many tables

Select TABLE1.Field1,TABLE1.Field2,TABLE2.Field1 from TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 on TABLE1.Field1=TABLE2.Field1